# Cannot send / receive mail to host server, but IMAP/SMTP login authenticates in mail.app

Tags: macos, email, dns, domain

I have Mac OS Server on a Mac mini. I have set up my own custom domain, and I have created a mail account on the server. The domain is registered with google, but for public DNS I am using afraid.org

I've created a SPF/TXT/MX record for mail.domain.com and domain.com
I can log in to it on my iPhone and my Mac. I can talk to the server off of my local network, but under mail it says the server reachability is "unknown."

I am a Comcast customer, so I have a feeling I'm either being blocked, or my mail account is listed as spam somehow. What perplexes me is this..

I can send email to user@domain.com, and I can even send FROM user@domain.com

However I NEVER receive the message. So if I send from user@domain.com to user@gmail.com, I never get the message. It says it was delivered / isn't sitting in an outbox. I check the gmail, never get it--not even in junk. I send from user@gmail.com to user@domain.com and receive nothing. Again gmail says it was delivered, it's in my sent box, and wasn't rejected by a mailer.

I can send / receive to myself. I use a relay server to send messages through Comcast, but again I don't get why my gmail / iCloud / exchange can't send and the account can't receive from external sources.

I made sure it wasn't a local network thing either, and I just sent / received from user@domain.com off of a public wifi. This is very confusing, and I don't even know how to clearly articulate the issue since it has so many different things that it could be.

Let me know whatever data you want / need to help. I'm not paying google for a mail server under my registered domain, this is more of a pet project.

If it could be one of several things, how can I test / confirm. The Mac OS Server client keeps a mail log, and a system log. I've heard it could be related to issues with Open Directory too, but I don't have that enabled.

Comment: can you telnet from the mac out to anyplace else on port 25?ie, `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`

Answer (score 0):

Many major email providers like Google, Microsoft, and etc. will not accept an email sent from a server that is not authoritative for the IP address from which the email is sent.

So, when you do an nslookup for you email server name or your domain name -- nslookup your domain.you will see your IP address reflected in the results, if you are using some DDNS setup.

However, if you do a reverse lookup, nslookup , you will not get back an authoritative reply with your domain name. When this happens, major mail providers drop the message.

The easiest way to sort this is to pay for a static IP through your provider, but this usually means paying for a business account at home. Other solutions includes paying for SMTP relay service, finding a friend with a business that pays for a business circuit and hosting your box there, and setting up a tertiary domain with an existing SMTP provider.

Comment: Google will accept but then flag and possibly spam-folder.  For "good to go to gmail" you need SPF/DKIM, proper reverse DNS, and SSL+SMTP/ESMTP